# Rails controller loop questions - update where exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a form where people can either create one cardrequest or many via uploading a csv file with ids. I have it working to simply create the requests. There are two things left I need to do in this routine that I am not sure how to do and looking for advice on.

1.) I need to check the ids either from the file upload or the single form field against an active table. If they are not active alert the person of that.

2.) If a combination of empid and cardholdergroup already exist update that request with the new params that were passed through.

Here is my action. Any thoughts on how/where I should do those? Any advice is appreciated.

```
      def create
        if cardrequest_params[:file].present?
          file_path = cardrequest_params[:file].path
          @cardholdergroups = cardrequest_params[:cardholdergroup_ids].map do |cardholdergroup_id|
          CSV.foreach(file_path) do |row|
            @cardrequest = Cardrequest.create(empid: row[0], startdate: cardrequest_params[:startdate], enddate: cardrequest_params[:enddate], user_id: current_user.id, cardholdergroup_ids: cardholdergroup_id)
           end
         end
        else
          @cardholdergroups = cardrequest_params[:cardholdergroup_ids].map do |cardholdergroup_id|
          @cardrequest = Cardrequest.create(empid: cardrequest_params[:empid], startdate: cardrequest_params[:startdate], enddate: cardrequest_params[:enddate], user_id: current_user.id, cardholdergroup_ids: cardholdergroup_id)
        end
        end
        respond_to do |format|
          if @cardrequest.save
            format.html { redirect_to cardrequests_path, notice: "Cardrequest was successfully created." }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @cardrequest }
          else
            format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            format.json { render json: @cardrequest.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's a couple different ways you could go about this. If it were me, I would take the CSV parsing out of the server end entirely and do it with something like the JS library PapaParse. Have it send each of the fields to your create function one at a time. You could then easily use the [find_or_create_by](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by) function or whatever logic you needed there to respond with a js message.

Then when they 'upload' with a csv file you could easily display a table of each of the csv line items and they're save/update results.

However, if you aren't a big javascript guy, I would at least separate the CSV upload from the create function into its own form.

```
# Cardrequest Controller
def csv_import
  Cardrequest.import(params[:file])
end
```

Make a route for it...

Then put clean things up further by putting the CSV parse logic into the model:

```
# Cardrequest Model
def self.import(file)
  # import logic here
  CSV.foreach(file, headers: true) do |row|
    row_hash = row.to_hash
    match = Cardrequest.find_or_create_by(unique: row_hash["unique"])
    match.update(#the rest of your data)
  end
end
```

Hopefully this helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will look into this.